# Writing a monotone function as the sum of two monotone functions

Tags: functions, monotone-functions

Let $\mathbb{N}\equiv \{1,2,3,...\}$. Could you suggest two functions $f_1: \mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f_2: \mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that

$f_1$ is monotone **decreasing**,

$f_2$ is monotone **increasing**, and

$f\equiv f_1+f_2$ is monotone **decreasing**.

I managed to find $f_1, f_2$ such that $f\equiv f_1+f_2$ is monotone **increasing** (e.g., $f_1(n)=n^2$, $f_2(n)=1/n$) but not the other way around.

---

Also, is there any theorem saying that any monotone (increasing or decreasing) function $f$ can be written as as the sum of a monotone increasing function $f_1$ and a monotone decreasing function $f_2$?

Comment: Your $f_2$ is not having a codomain in $N$

Comment: I assume you want these functions to be strictly increasing and decreasing, as otherwise any two constant functions would work, but then I'm a bit confused about how to have a strictly decreasing function on the naturals since you can only decrease so far...  Also, your $f_2$ is not a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @JohnWatson, yes, my mistake, question edited

Comment: @lulu the question has been edited

Comment: So, what about $f_1(n)=-2n$, $f_2(n)=n$?

Comment: @cjohnson  the functions I am looking for could be flat for some parts of the domain but not constant in the entire domain

Comment: Sure.  $f_1(n)=-n^2$, $f_2(n)=n$  (shift by $1$ if you are worried about $n=0$).

Comment: @lulu thank you. If you have time to provide an answer below, it would be helpful. Also to my last question regarding the existence of a theorem.

Comment: The theorem should be easy to prove.  Say $f$ is monotone increasing.  Then let $f_+=2f$, $f_-=-f$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f$ denote any monotone decreasing function from $\mathbb N\to \mathbb R$.  Then let $f_1=2f$, $f_2=-f$. And similarly if $f$ is monotone increasing.

Taking, say, $f(n)=-n$ gives a particular example, but the general construction establishes the theorem you requested.

Comment: Thanks. Does the theorem has well known name in math? Can it be restricted by requiring $f_1, f_2$ of different degree?

Comment: I don't suppose this has a name.  In general, the degree of a function is not defined.  If you specify that $f$ is a polynomial, then of course there is the notion of a degree and I think you should be able to play with examples to show that you can always vary the degree (hint:  you can always add and subtract $n^k$ from your function).

Answer (score 2):

Let $f_1(x)$ have slope $m$. The general idea is to have $f_2(x)$ increasing but have a slope less than $|m|$, so that overall $f_1(x) + f_2(x)$ is **decreasing**.

You can do this with straight lines: Let $f_1(x) = -x$, and $f_2(x)$ be $\frac{1}{2}x$. Then $f_1(x)+f_2(x) = -\frac{1}{2}x$. Here's an illustration of this on [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/iul4csh1qo).

Comment: Thank you. What about my last question?

Comment: We can let $f_1(x)$ be $-x$ when $x≥0$, and $0$ when $x<0$. We can also let $f_2(x)$ be $\frac{1}{2}x$ when $x≥0$, and $0$ when $x<0$.

Comment: I meant from the main text "Also, is there any theorem saying that any monotone (increasing or decreasing) function $f$ can be written as as the sum of a monotone increasing function $f_1$ and a monotone decreasing function $f_2$?"

Comment: Also, what happens when the slope is not constant and equal to $m$, but it varies with $x$?

Comment: @STF For your second question, when $\frac{dy}{dx} = kx$, it has the solution $\frac{kx^2}{2} + c$. However, this function is not monotone. However, when $\frac{dy}{dx} = kx^2$, the solution is $\frac{kx^3}{3} + c$ which is monotone. (Look, I'm really bumping into calculus here..., if you don't know calculus I'm sorry)

Comment: @STF I really can't prove your first question - you'll really have to leave it to someone else (unless one of the functions can be constant).